# Android - Connecting to the Flickr API and grabbing photos in Java

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

I am currently working on an Android app and I am trying to connect to Flickr and grab photos from it. However, my HttpGet call fails completely. Here is my code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String temp = restUrl.toString();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(temp);
try
{
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity();
        if (httpEntity != null)
        {
            InputStream inStream = httpEntity.getContent();
            Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String stringReadline = null;
            while ((stringReadline = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                sBuilder.append(stringReadline+"\n");
            }
            queryResult = sBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
```

My temp stores the string "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=467ae9bf5926d10c684d4f47d7da6434&tags=new%20york&per_page=5&page1"

The call works fine when I make the call in my browser (It returns the xml file I am expecting). However, it does not work when I am making the call from my android app. I have added the Internet permissions line in my android manifest file.

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Ro

Comment: you should take your API key out of this question. just an fyi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup didn't read your full question before I posted my answer.

I have used code below to retrieve content and it works with no problems.

```
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = response.getEntity().getContent();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    try{
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
            total.append(line); 
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
            return null
    }

    return queryResult = total.toString();
```

Comment: Hi, What exactly is the 'request' parameter you pass into httpClient.execute(...)?

Comment: Never - mind. Thanks a lot. That part of the code is working perfectly.